# Need Help to integrate JBoss (wildfly) with IIS

Tags: iis, jboss, wildfly

We are in the process of migrating our web site from  Coldfusion to JBoss (wildfly). The current application with Coldfusion runs via IIS6 since our application runs on multiple language (.Net,PHP,java). We have successfully migrated our app to JBoss (wildfly) and in the process of going live. But We couldn't get any successful guide/steps to integrate the app with **IIS7**. Please do help us to run our JBoss(Wildfly) site via IIS7, with proper step by step guide.

We are totally forsaken, Please help us.

Answer (score 2):

That is quite simple, WildFly is accessible via http or ajp protocols.

configuration of the listeners is in undertow subsystem and by default you have http.

so if you go with http listener which listened on port 8080, all you need to do is configure reverse proxy on IIS7+ to proxy requests to ip-of-wildfly-server:8080

Other option is to use AJP protocol for which you need to first add  to undertow subsystem in wildfly. 
Then you need to properly install & configure [isapi_redirect](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html) to forward request to wildfly on ajp port you configured.

In short it is not much different than configuring it for tomcat or jboss as. 
For more details on how to configure undertow subsystem see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Undertow+subsystem+configuration